# How can I evaluate VS build command macros?

Tags: visual-studio

It's more often obvious what a build command macro like $(SolutionDir) will evaluate to, but when building complex strings of these macros, it would be nice to be able to quickly evaluate the resulting real string.  Is there any way of doing this except building a custom tool that takes a string of macros as input and outputs the evaluated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a pre-build event and use "echo" to display the string in the Output window

```
 echo $(SolutionDir)
```

Comment: Nice, but is there any way of cancelling the build after doing that?