# dotnet watch $(SolutionDir) is *Undefined*

Tags: c#, .net-core, watch

I'm trying to use dotnet watch however my project references nuget package which uses $(SolutionDir) to copy some files in prebuild event. It kinda make sense because dotnet watch is run on project level so $(SolutionDir) doesn't exist. Is there any way to run dotnet watch for entire solution?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439060/how-can-i-evaluate-vs-build-command-macros

Comment: @SurajS it will display $(SolutionDir) value but I know it's null. How would it help in my scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a batch script `watch.bat`

```
call SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
call SET SolutionDir=%~dp0\\..\\..\\
call dotnet watch run
```

Added a script in `package.json`:

```
 "scripts": { "dotnetwatch": "watch.bat" }
```

Now I can run it like this from CLI:

```
npm run dotnetwatch
```

or from within visual studio with the following `launchsettings.json` profile:

```
"dotnet watch": {
      "executablePath": "watch",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

It's not an ideal solution but at least it's good enough for me.

Answer (score -1):

As of dotnet-watch 2.0.0-preview2, it is not possible to run dotnet watch on solution files. However, you can construct a custom 'project' for the watcher that will watch multiple projects. See https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/tree/rel/2.0.0-preview2/samples/dotnet-watch/WatchMultipleProjects for a complete sample of how to do this.

Comment: it doesn't really answer my question. In my projects I have to have defined $(SolutionDir) property. With msbuild I can just do msbuild /p:SolutionDir=whatever but in dotnet cli it doesn't seem to work.